# Make ScrollBar Under Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the scrollbar hidden under a specific element and when it scrolls out out of it becomes visible again.

I hope the picture below will clarify what I mean.

[image]

**Here's my code:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: See This [Screen Shot](https://prnt.sc/fjgnod)